# How to know the orientation (whether clockwise or anticlockwise) of the curve C

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, orientation

How to know the orientation (whether clockwise or anticlockwise) of the curve C: $(3/2)(x+y)^2+(x-y)^2/2=1$ whose parametrization is given by $$x=\frac{1}{\sqrt 6}\cos \theta -\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\sin\theta, ~~y=\frac{1}{\sqrt 6}\cos \theta +\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\sin\theta$$

NB: Taking $x+y=\sqrt{2/3} \cos \theta$ and $x-y=-\sqrt 2 \sin \theta$

**Answer:**

On $xy$-plane, at $\theta=0$, $(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt 6}(1,1)$ which is up and $(dx/d\theta,dy/d\theta)=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(-1,1)$ which is to the left. So the motion is anticlockwise.

**My doubt:**

1. I am unable to understand the argument. What is the logic behind it? Please help me to understand.
2. Why $x-y$ is not considered as $x-y=+\sqrt 2 \sin \theta$?

Edit: I know that "A curve has positive orientation if a region R is on the left when travelling around the boundary of R"

Comment: How did you get $z = - \frac{2}{\sqrt6} \cos\theta$?

Comment: I am surprised there is a $z$-component. I don't see how in $3$ dimensions clockwise or anti-clockwise orientation can be defined. These are $2D$ concepts.

Comment: You may find this answer useful:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/218860/1061348

Comment: @Henry Request for a specific explanation for this example...

Comment: @MathLover Edited the problem...what is the logic behind this... would you kindly explain ...

Comment: @MathLover Is the logic true: " the tangent vector represented by $(dx/d\theta,dy/d\theta)=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(-1,1)$ is showing left oriented"?

Comment: No it does not make sense. A curve given by $(3/2)(x+y)^2+(x-y)^2/2=1$ can be oriented either clockwise or anti-clockwise. The given answer does not make sense to me.

Comment: @MathLover True..I want to know under what parametrization, the curve orients anticlockwise?

Comment: Does it make sense now...